# How to set firefox to not share information with web sites (browser version, screen resolution, OS, etc.)?

Tags: firefox, browser, privacy, anonymity

so, does anybody knows how to turn off information sharing?
This is the kind of information i don't wish to share with websites:
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: This question is not in scope for StackOverflow, but check out https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2019/04/09/protections-against-fingerprinting-and-cryptocurrency-mining-available-in-firefox-nightly-and-beta/

Comment: sorry.. And thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to close the question.
Answered by [Nickolay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026/nickolay)